# How to use broadcast to sum two different shape arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two arrays and want to sum them using numpy broadcasting. This is the first array:

```
[4 6 2 1]
```

And the second :

```
[[ 5  4  56  45]
 [ 10  7  88  120]
 [69 9 70 1]]
```

How can I sum this two arrays using numpy broadcasting? I Appreciate your help

**Update**

```
a = np.array(a)
A = np.array(A)

G = a + A
```

result:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-4fac93342c82> in <module>()
      5 A = np.array(A)
      6 
----> 7 G = a + A
      8 #print(G)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3, 4)
```

Comment: We don't know what output you expect. Also the arrays are not very copy/paste friendly

Comment: I want to change the shape of vector a so that the broadcast can occur

Comment: And I could sum the two arrays

Comment: `a+b` should broadcast them both, since the shapes are compatible. Have you tried that?

Comment: I did it but it throws this error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably like this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([4, 6, 2, 1])
B = np.array([[ 5,  4,  56,  45],
 [ 10,  7,  88,  120],
 [69, 9, 70, 1]])

C = A + B
print(C)
>>> [[  9  10  58  46]
     [ 14  13  90 121]
     [ 73  15  72   2]]
```

You don't need to change the shape, to numpy they are already broadcastable. You have `A.shape = (4,)` and `B.shape = (3, 4)`. So numpy will broadcast into the first dimension of `B`.

Comment: I did exactly like that but it throws this error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,6)

Comment: Your input array is not (4,6) @MilhouseVanHouten ...

Comment: My mistake, is (3,4)

Comment: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,4)

Comment: you sure you didn't made a mistake copying, or even left out a comma? If I copy paste it I get exactly that result.

Comment: could you print out the shapes before you put them together? and print out the arrays as well. maybe we can fix this :)

Comment: the shapes are (3,4) for the larger array and (4,) for the smaller in both before and after the conversion. The values are in the post

Comment: I'm stucked on it

Comment: Are you there ?